# Intersection of 2 arrays

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, arrays, binary-search

Here is a question i came across :

> Given two arrays, write a function to compute their intersection.Here we will allow the duplicates.
>
> Note:
>   Each element in the result should appear as many times as it shows in both arrays.
>   The result can be in any order.
>
> Example 1:
>   Input: nums1 = [1,2,2,1], nums2 = [2,2]  --->  *Output: [2,2]*

we can solve this using *Hashing/2-pointer/Binary-search* methods.But here is a *follow-up question* ,

**What if elements of nums2 are stored on disk, and the memory is limited such that you cannot load all elements into the memory at once?**

How to solve then ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting